# Convert string to dictionary where keys are not strings

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am parsing an html file an I end up with something that *almost* looks like a python dictionary... except for the keys not being strings. Because of this I cannot use `ast.literal_eval()` or `json.loads()`.

The string looks like this:

```
x = '{name:'Berlin, Germany', daypart:'night', href:'/en/de/berlin/10178/weather-forecast/178087', icon:'http://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2010/images/icons-numbered/33-m.png', bg:'cl', temp:'22',  realfeel:'22',  text:'Clear'}'
```

I want to convert this into a python dictionary where the keys are also strings. I think this need some good ol' regex but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's valid JavaScript, not JSON or Python, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but I am trying to convert it to a python dict

Comment: try `literal_eval(re.sub(r"(\w+)(?=:')",r"'\1'",x))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, why not post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @HerrActress, because not sure how robust it is! If it is always in the format `key:'` then it will work, might need to catch a few more cases though

Comment: This might be a bit more robust, `it = iter(re.findall(r"(\w+|[\'\"].*?[\'\"])", x));dict(zip(it,it))`

Comment: do a replace for all `:'` and `',` to use double quotes, then pass the whole string into `json.loads(..)`

Comment: Is this really as simple to do as some say ? I don't think so. But, it _looks_ simple.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can follow @Zero Piraeus' suggestion from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029320/fix-unquoted-keys-in-json-like-file-so-that-it-uses-correct-json-syntax#31030022) and use a YAML parser like [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) to read your string and then convert the result to a dictionary.